# Single Phase Diode Bridge Rectifier - Inductive Smoothing Question

Tags: diodes, inductor, rectifier, bridge

[image: Exam Question for Power Supply Electronics]

So I don't understand how the answer is 2.124 volt-seconds when if you put the equation through a calculator it comes out as -0.174. Is there an additional mathematical step to do on the cosines in square brackets?

Comment: Cos (180) is -1 but there is a minus sign in front of that part of the equation so the answer that you have  (-0.174) cannot be true - a negative answer is wrong for the formula given. I get 2.1239257 FYI.

Answer (score 1):

You are solving the equation correctly, except that your calculator is in radian mode.  Switch it to degree mode, and you should get the correct answer (= 2.124).